# Why does int32.maxvalue + 1 overflow a long?

Tags: c#, .net

If you put the following code in a .NET 4.5 application:

```
public const long MAXIMUM_RANGE_MAGNITUDE = int.MaxValue + 1;
```

A compiler error is generated stating "The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode". I know that I could put this in an "unchecked" block and be fine, but my question is why does the error appear in the first place? Clearly a long can hold a int's max value plus one.

Note that using Int32 and Int64 instead of long and int does not seem to help.

Comment: It doesn't overflow a long; it overflows an int.

Comment: When the runtime evaluate this it takes a 32Bit integer and adds 1 to it.

Comment: so the only way to do this is in unchecked mode?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is because the calculations on the right hand side of assignment is being done in integer type. And it is **overflowing integer**

You can fix that with:

```
public const long MAXIMUM_RANGE_MAGNITUDE = int.MaxValue + (long)1; // or 1L
```

By casting at least one of the operand to long

The reason you get the error is specified in C# specifications.

**See [C# Specification Section 4.1.5 (Integral types)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)**

> For the binary +, –, *, /, %, &, ^, |, ==, !=, >, <, >=, and <=
>   operators, the operands are converted to type T, where T is the first
>   of int, uint, long, and ulong **that can fully represent all possible
>   values of both operands.** The operation is then performed using the
>   precision of type T, and the type of the result is T (or bool for the
>   relational operators). It is not permitted for one operand to be of
>   type long and the other to be of type ulong with the binary operators.

In your case since both operands of addition can be represented in `int` therefore the calculation is done in integer type. Explicitly casting one of the operand to `long` would result in `long` result and thus no overflow error.

Comment: Great answer, I tried a couple of variations on the code you posted, but apparently not the right one! Yours works great though.

Answer (score 4):

Your code in fact looks like this:

```
(long)(int.MaxValue + 1)
```

But because .Net framework has an inbuilt implicit conversion between int and long you do not have to explicitly put a cast to long in your code.

So firstly this part of the code is executed:

```
int.MaxValue + 1
```

and the result of this operation is an `int` value which causes and overflow exception. 
So your code does not even have a chance to start the conversion from int to long.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the value of `int.MaxValue + 1` being calculated *before* the cast to `long` is made. Certainly a long can hold the value, but because you are doing integer addition, there is no way to store the integer value of `int.MaxValue + 1` in an int until the cast is made.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public const long MAXIMUM_RANGE_MAGNITUDE = (long)int.MaxValue + 1L;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the constant value to a long.

```
public const long MAXIMUM_RANGE_MAGNITUDE = (long) int.MaxValue + 1;
```